# parameter expansion with separator in the sh and ksh shell

Tags: shell, sh, ksh

I have a problem similar to the one solve in this question: [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash) .

The real difference is that I'm targeting the `sh` and `ksh` shell so, for example, I can't use the `<<<` redirection.

To recap my problem I have the content of a variable that is

```
VALUES="
val1    ;val2    ;val3
another1;another2;another3
"
```

so clearly the whitespace  and `;` are the characters that I would like to get rid of.

I also have to use this values as they appear in a 3 by 3 basis, 3 at the time, but I assume that for that I can simply use `$1`,`$2` and `$3` after the expansion plus a `shift 3` at the end of each cycle.

Thanks.

Comment: @blueberryfields I guess that that will work, but it would be nice to discuss something that wasn't requiring any external tool, just to see if this is possible with the `sh` or `ksh`, using an external tool it's not really like targeting a specific shell, it's just ... using an external tool.

Comment: Huh? The accepted answer for that other question uses pure shell, no external tools (though Awk is usually available in some form) and no Bash.

Comment: @tripleee I guess that I read that `<<` as `<<<`; but you are right, that should work too, I missed that somehow ...

Comment: @tripleee but that solution doesn't really cope that well with cycles and iterations, the solution given here does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
VALUES="
val1    ;val2    ;val3
another1;another2;another3
"
echo "$VALUES" | while IFS=' ;' read v1 v2 v3; do 
    [[ -z $v1 && -z $v2 && -z $v3 ]] && continue
    echo "v1=$v1  v2=$v2  v3=$v3"
done
```

```
v1=val1  v2=val2  v3=val3
v1=another1  v2=another2  v3=another3
```

---

Re-reading your question, you're talking about arrays. Here you go:

```
typeset -a values
typeset -i i=0
echo "$VALUES" | while IFS=' ;' read v1 v2 v3; do
    [[ -z $v1 && -z $v2 && -z $v3 ]] && continue
    values[i]=$v1
    values[i+1]=$v2
    values[i+2]=$v3
    ((i+=3))
done

for i in "${!values[@]}"; do printf "%d\t%s\n" $i "${values[i]}"; done
```

```
0   val1
1   val2
2   val3
3   another1
4   another2
5   another3
```

Comment: this looks perfect, the use of `IFS` makes it neat and easy to customize, thanks!

Comment: +1: QQ isnt `[[..]]` bash construct?

Comment: @jaypal, works in ksh and zsh. I think ksh did it first.

Comment: to be clear I know that the `[[ ]]` syntax doesn't work under the `sh`, but this post gave me the right hint to complete my script and support the `sh` too as well .

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk and reduce all the complexity:

```
echo "$VALUES"|awk -F' *; *' 'NF>1{print $1, $2, $3}'
val1 val2 val3
another1 another2 another3
```

Comment: thanks, the problem with this is that I don't really have to print the values, and I would prefer to simply not use external tools, I would like to create something more like an array of values and shift them 3 by 3 when reading.